# Keeping nanosecond precision on committing pandas dataframe to oracle db

Tags: oracle, pandas

I'm currently working with python on a data set with nanosecond timestamps. I have the data in a pandas DataFrame and am trying to use the to_sql method to commit to an oracle database using sqlalchemy as the engine.

It seems like the automatic resolution of timestamps in oracle is microseconds and so I'm losing some precision on the commit. Is there someway that I can specify that I want to commit to nanosecond resolution?

I've tried pre-creating the table with TIMESTAMP(9) but this also hasn't worked.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First, you are saying that _is not working_ but there is no explanation why (I mean, what part is not working). Second, try logging/print what you are sending towards the DB and make sure you are passing the correct data (note that if you are invoking a function with the timestamp as a parameter, the type of the parameter within the function declaration must be compatible with your needs of course).

Comment: Hi FDavidov, thanks for the feedback.  To clarify, the data that is being stored in the Oracle database has only microsecond precision and so is losing the nanoseconds. As for the function, the timestamps are being passed as part of a call to self in the method. I'm not explicitly passing them. I am trying to set the dtype though and as far as i'm aware there is no way to pass another argument to sqlalchemy.types.TIMESTAMP

Comment: What I meant is that, through the whole path the timestamp passes through, you must make sure that the storing/receiving variables are defined consistently (i.e. `TIMESTAMP(9)`). You mentioned that tried defining the field in the table as such, but if you don't define all other variables/parameters with the same type, whatever you send will at some point be truncated.